# Oracle Apex - Select list populates text field

Tags: list, select, dynamic, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 4.2. I have a select list and a text field. I'm trying to create a dynamic action that should be simple enough but I'm not sure how to do it. Basically depending on what value the user selects from the list of values in the select list, the text field should then be populated. So for example:

Let's say the select list gives the user the choice to select 'Animal', 'Car', 'Person'. If the user selects 'Animal' then the text field should immediately have the value 'cat'. If the user selects 'Car' then the text field should immediately have the value 'toyota'. If the user selects 'Person@ then the text field should immediately have the value 'jim' etc.

How would I make this dynamic action?

Thanks,
Stephen.

Comment: Are these lists fixed, or are they looked up in the database?

Comment: Hi @PaulWalker

the list of values in the select list are got by querying a table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a New Dynamic Action with the following properties

### Main Properties

- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item
- Item(s): [Select List]
- Condition: No Condition

### True Action

- Action: Execute PL/SQL code
- Fire When event Result is: True
- PL/SQL Code:

  #### Option 1 - use a lookup table

  ```
  select LOOKUP_VALUE
  into :P1_TEXT
  from LOOKUP_TABLE
  where original_value = :P1_SELECT_LIST;
  ```

  #### Option 2 - Use hardcoded values

  ```
  CASE upper(:P1_SELECT_LIST)
      WHEN 'ANIMAL' THEN :P1_TEXT := 'cat';
      WHEN 'CAR' THEN :P1_TEXT := 'toyota';
      WHEN 'PERSON' THEN :P1_TEXT := 'jim';
      ELSE :P1_TEXT := null;
  END CASE;
  ```
- Page Items to Submit: [P1_SELECT_LIST]
- Page Items to Return [P1_TEXT]

Comment: Good answer, but when you posted this it wasn't specified that a table lookup is required. Your javascript solution therefor won't be of service and you'd need to replace it with ajax code. However, the PLSQL option is exactly what @StephenWalsh needs, except that in the PLSQL code there should be a SQL that does the actual lookup. Change that up a bit and you'll get my vote :)

Comment: Thanks @RohanM 

I tried the PL/SQL option first and it worked perfectly, thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks Tom, I straightened out my answer as suggested.